# How to make it safer my restful API using Django + OAuth2?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I am developing an application both android and ios and also I'm using Django rest framework. this app do not have a login page. There is online facebook login page.

I did search a lot and I found these two library for this

```
pip install python-social-auth ( actually it has new name which is social-auth-app-django)
pip install django-oauth-toolkit
```

However, somebody told me that you don't have to use these library. Facebook login has oauth already.

This is the problem, How can I do this ?
How can I use facebook Login to make powerfull API.

Comment: Can you use [requests_oauthlib](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/facebook.html)?

Comment: I can try. What do you think about that library. Is that safe etc.etc ?@Raz

Comment: Yes. It is an extension for `requests` lib which is de facto standard in python.

Comment: is there any other documant documentation about this ? @Raz

Comment: I just checked django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 documentation. Did you try to just follow [this](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2#facebook-example) example?

Comment: python-social-auth has been changed so it did not work. I tryed before @Raz

Comment: It should work. It is used by a lot of projects. If you have issues with it make another question and describe your problem.

Comment: It worked I gues. However, how can I send request from my android application. @Raz

Comment: curl -X POST -d "grant_type=convert_token&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&backend=facebook&token=<facebook_token>" http://localhost:8000/auth/convert-token

this is not possible